# The query operator 'ToDictionary' is not supported

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I am using following query to get dictionary:

```
 using (JSEADataContext dc = new JSEADataContext(JSEADBContext.GetConnectionstring()))
                {
                   var Incident = (from incident in dc.Incidents
                                      from main in dc.Mains.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                      from teamApproval in dc.TeamsAndApprovals.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                      where incident.reportid == "123123"
                                      orderby incident.reportid ascending
                                      select new Data
                                      {
      AssessmentFormCount = (from assessmentCount in dc.Table1
                                                                 join panel in dc.Table2 on assessmentCount.lng_ID equals panel.lng_id
                                                                 into temp
                                                                 from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                 where assessmentCount.ReportID == main.ReportID
                                                                 group j by j.str_desc into grouping
                                                                 select new AssessmentFormCheckedCount
                                                                     {
                                                                         str_Panel = grouping.Key,
                                                                         lng_Count = grouping.Count()
                                                                     }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(id => id.str_Panel, id => id.lng_Count) }).ToList<Data>().SingleOrDefault();
}



 public class AssessmentFormCheckedCount
    {
        public string str_Panel { get; set; }
        public int lng_Count { get; set; }
    }

 public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
       #region Assessment Count
        private AssessmentFormCheckedCount _AssessmentFormCount { get; set; }
        public AssessmentFormCheckedCount AssessmentFormCount
        {
            get
            {
                return this._AssessmentFormCount;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._AssessmentFormCount != value))
                {

                    this._AssessmentFormCount = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("AssessmentFormCount");

                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
}
```

**Problem:**

When i am trying to execute this i am getting

> The query operator 'ToDictionary' is not supported

where i am going wrong in this.

Comment: `ToDictionary` then `ToList` then `SingleOrDefault` ? That's a weird combination.

Comment: As you can see i am using as a subquery. It means for single object there is multiple count for different panels.

Comment: I don't think you can use .`ToDictionary` in a SubQuery. Because in Linq-To-Sql, both the outer and inner query are executed in One-Go. With that said, the provider is not able to translate the inner query into SQL ! You need to rethink your query, or maybe create a stored procedure an call it using Linq-2-SQL. That's one huge query to return a single value !

Comment: ok, You want to say that if a class contain object list type property and dictionary type property. In this case we are not able to bind them as subquery right?

Comment: What user3185569 say is correct, if want do sub-query, you can use "let" keyword in Linq.

Comment: @HarrisYer Thanks. Can you implement "let" in my query?

Comment: @HarrisYer - A `let` assignment won't help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to call `.ToDictionary(id => id.str_Panel, id => id.lng_Count) })` within an `IQueryable<T>`, that is being run on a SQL server, and there is no way to convert `ToDictionary` to a SQL command.

So, even though it is valid C# code, it just can't be converted to valid SQL. What you need to do is make sure that your `IQueryable<T>` can be converted to SQL, and then call `.ToList()` (or `.ToArray()`) on the result to pull it in to memory. Then you can call `.ToDictionary(...)` on the result.

Something like this:

```
var Incident =
(
    from incident in dc.Incidents
    from main in dc.Mains.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from teamApproval in dc.TeamsAndApprovals.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where incident.reportid == "123123"
    orderby incident.reportid ascending
    select
    (
        from assessmentCount in dc.Table1
        join panel in dc.Table2 on assessmentCount.lng_ID equals panel.lng_id
        into temp
        from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where assessmentCount.ReportID == main.ReportID
        group j by j.str_desc into grouping
        select new
        {
            str_Panel = grouping.Key,
            lng_Count = grouping.Count()
        }
    )
).Take(1).ToList();

var result =
    Incident
        .Select(xs => xs.ToDictionary(id => id.str_Panel, id => id.lng_Count))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am calling one method instead of query which contain same query and it is working fine now.

```
using (JSEADataContext dc = new JSEADataContext(JSEADBContext.GetConnectionstring()))
                {
                   var Incident = (from incident in dc.Incidents
                                      from main in dc.Mains.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                      from teamApproval in dc.TeamsAndApprovals.Where(inv => inv.ReportID == incident.reportid).DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                      where incident.reportid == "123123"
                                      orderby incident.reportid ascending
                                      select new Data
                                      {
      AssessmentFormCount = test(main.str_ReportID, dc) }).ToList<Data>().SingleOrDefault();
}




 private Dictionary<string, int> test(string ReportID, DataContext dc)
    {
        var ceck = (from assessmentCount in dc.AssessmentForms.AsEnumerable()
                    join panel in dc.masters.AsEnumerable() on assessmentCount.lng_ID equals panel.lng_id
                    into temp
                    from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where assessmentCount.ReportID == ReportID
                    group j by j.desc into grouping
                    select new AssessmentFormCheckedCount
                        {
                            str_Panel = grouping.Key,
                            lng_Count = grouping.Count()
                        }).ToList();
        var t = ceck.ToDictionary(p => p.str_Panel, p => p.lng_Count);
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: This Method work because the test method already call .ToList(), mean it already execute the query and return Enumerable list.

Comment: @Sunny - Why did you answer your own question with a non-answer? You should delete this and add this to the end of your question as an edit.

Comment: Thanks @HarrisYer.

Comment: @Enigmativity i can mark it as answer after two days.

Comment: @Sunny - But it isn't an answer. It's a code dump. It doesn't help future readers. You need to explain what you did to fix the issue and why it works.